# UItableviewcontroller SizeToFit not working on UILabel field

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, sizetofit

Hi I am using sizetofit on my UILabel field, it works fine when I load the tableview controller, but then starts cutting of letters and wrapping to another line when I scroll up and down. Here is the code I use in CellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"subjectCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    // Configure the cell...

    // Load and display subject photo image
    UIImageView *subjectImageView = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:200];
    subjectImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:subjectImages[indexPath.row]];


    // Load and display subject label
    UILabel *subjectLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:201];
    subjectLabel.text = [subjectItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [subjectLabel sizeToFit];// call this to fit size of the label according to text



    return cell;
}
```

And here is a screen shot of my tableviewcontroller originaly loaded:

[image]

And here after scrolling up and down you can see the descriptions have been cut

[image]

Thanks for any help you can give to solve this.

Cheers

Carson

Comment: Show your `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method.

Comment: @rmaddy see above I am now showing the full cellForRowAtIndexPath

Comment: Try `setNeedDisplay` after `sizeToFit`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `sizeToFit` for `UILabel` can cause a mess like this in `UITableView` with reusing cells. One of solutions I can think of is to set the width of the frame for your label width before you call `sizeToFit` and you have to do this every time you assign text to the label. It should look something like this:

```
CGRect frame = subjectLabel.frame;
frame.size.width = 100.0; //try to adjust this value 
subjectLabel.frame = frame;
[subjectLabel sizeToFit];
```

Comment: Thanks very much, thats fixed it :-)